# Where is `Sketchpad` moved to in gradio?

Tags: python-3.x, gradio

In [change log of 3.4](https://www.gradio.app/changelog), gradio introduced the sketchpad component.

But in the current version, `gr.Sketchpad` is not defined.

Where is the component moved to?

```py
import gradio as gr

demo = gr.Interface(
    lambda x: x, gr.Sketchpad(), gr.Image()
)

demo.launch()
```

[image]